# Ubuntu 14.04.1 - Help please to setup VPN

Tags: 14.04, networking, vpn, openvpn

I use VPN from www.privateinternetaccess.com

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04.1.

The VPN provider provided me with Beta version of special software which kills all traffic of PC except VPN so if VPN is turned off - there is no traffic and internet as well, if VPN is turned on - Itnernet works.

Here is that software with guide:

> Here is a link to our linux beta client if you would like to try it.
>
> https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/installer/download_installer_linux
>
> From the terminal in the directory you downloaded to:
>
> 1) Extract file: tar -xvf installer_linux.tar.gz
>
> 2) Tell OS to proceed: chmod +x installer_linux.sh
>
> 3) Run installer: ./installer_linux.sh

All works fine, but my main Wi-Fi connection still has all manual setup as is was before VPN install, such as.

Main ip - 192.168.1.2
Mask - 255.255.255.0
gateway - 192.168.1.1
DNS - 192.168.1.1

So, what I'm afraid that this sofware can glitch and my real IP will be seen due the main route is working. And actually lot's of the people who use VPN think that their IP is hided but in 90% of cases it is not - bacause many of VPN providers doesn't bother about that fact. If you have working default route the traffic will go to the easiest way, and sometime easiest way is default route.

I want to setup VPN access manually so I can control it 100%.

I've done the same on my Windows based PC and it works perfect -
all what I've dont is removed Gaterway from Wi-Fi connection IPv4 properties add added 
new route such as "  add route (ip of VPN) mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.1"

And all works just perfect I have 3-4 regional VPN connections and 3-4 added routes via CMD.( on Windows)
All works just perfect. When you connected to VPN - you have Intenet. As soon as it dropped - you've got no Internet. SO I'm clicking "connect" corresponding VPN connection - and Internet appears.
It' could be not very comfort but for the total control of your IP - it's perfect.

Can you help me to setup exactly the same scheme of VPN work on Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 0):

Use OpenVPN, it should install with:

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn
```

Start it by typing:

```
 sudo openvpn --config /path/to/config/file
```